# Understanding capacitive load conditions for a microcontroller

Tags: capacitance, signal-integrity

This is from a PIC24E microcontroller datasheet.

[image]

My question is understand what does "load conditions for device timing" mean ?
Does it mean in order to maintain timing (say for a high speed PWM signal, or anything a designer wishes to maintain a sharp edge), the capacitive load ( parasitics + receive input) must be a max of 50pF ?

I'm confused about Table 32-15. Are these special case in which the Figure 32-1 is not true? For instance, Figure 32-1 states that all I/O have a CL = 50pF except for OSC2 which is 15pF. This will apply to all clocking modes and table 32-15 gives exceptions to this, such as OSC2 is not 15pF when in EC mode.

Comment: I believe that they are specifying the load conditions used (i.e. a model of what they attached) when they tested the timing characteristics of the device.

Comment: as Sarrk said, the timing parameters they mentioned are measured using this arrangement. from this, if your scenario is different you need to simulate accordingly (like less load or higher load than expected)

Comment: The capacitive loading requirements are maximums and are most obvious for I2C. If your I2C line length is so long or you have so many devices hanging off it that the total line capacitance exceeds 400pF, then you are out of spec (may not work).

Comment: There is a first order RC circuit with an exponential current/voltage waveform.  Remember that in the Load-2 Condition there is an instant where the pin needs to source very high current (As if the Capacitor was ground) which exponentially dies off.  I would argue the load is this voltage waveform or its derivative (Current).  Similarly in load condition 1 the pin will be sinking high current for an instant which exponentially dies off.

Answer (score 1):

The first table clearly says "Load Conditions for Device Timing Specifications". That means that the rise and fall times specified in other areas of the datasheet (typical 5ns maximum 25ns for one I looked at) are to be measured with that load. It's not a maximum per se, but if your load capacitance exceeds the 15pF you can't complain if a port pin takes 26ns to rise/fall- which most likely would happen at a temperature extreme.

Table 32-15 is a bit different-it indicates the **maximum** load on the pins in question for the part to function properly. You should not exceed a 50pF load directly (no series resistance) on the port pins, nor on the OSC2 output. The 15pF maximum load on OSC2 when an external oscillator input is used is because that output is also the input to the clock of the microcontroller, so if one loads it excessively it could slow the edges down enough to compromise operation of the micro. The 400pF loading on the I2C pins indicates it conforms to the [NXP (née Philips) spec](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10216.pdf) for unbuffered 400k I2C.

Answer (score 0):

Taking things at face value this is how I would interpret the data sheet:

The specified parameters are maximums below which operation is guaranteed.
Lower values are permitted.

Table 32-1 refers to a subset of the total conditions.
SOME parameters may be relaxed beyond what the table allows in SOME special conditions, but abiding by 32-1 will guarantee operation.
This is 'naughty but safe'.

32-1 misses the "special cases" of

- OSC2 when in EC mode and
- SCLx and SDAx in I2C operation.

32-15 lists the special cases.

---

**The following are assumptions which I'd hope were correct:**

I assume EC = External Clock.
In cases where a resonant device (crystal, ceramic resonator, ...) is applied to C1 and C2, C2 is the output of an external gate which is used to provide 'drive' to the resomator which provides feebcak energy via the resonator to C1. If C2 has significant caapacitance it may do any or all of modify the operation of the resonator and either change frequency or prevent or modify startup and oscillator stability. When an external clock is provided C1 is driven by the clock without feedback from C2 and C2 "goes along for the ride". All the output pf the internal gate is available to drive the capacitance at the pin so a higher than otherwsie value is permitted.

The IIC drive pins expect to drive IIC and when in this mode the internal drivers are specified to drive the sort of loads expected in this mode.